# Android TV Debugging via ADB Device NOT FOUND

Tags: android, adb, android-tv, android-debug

Im currently developing a TV App and currently working with Android emulator until my actual TV device came, now my problem is I can't find a way to debug my app with the actual device.

I tried ADB but after I set the tcpip 5555 no device/emulator is found.

1. Yes, it has the same network as my PC
2. Debug mode on Developers mode is turned On
3. Cable is connected
4. I can ping the device IP via cmd and all good

I am currently following this steps by [Google](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv#using_android_debug_bridge) which is also the same when setting up wireless debugging on mobile phone (And I made it working with mobile devices but not with Android TV)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which Android TV devices are you using?

Comment: @MorrisonChang  TCL Android TV

Comment: I had tested a couple of Android TVs (Sony Bravia and NVidia Shield) and it worked straight away for both of them wireless and wired.

You can try using just "adb connect IP" without the 5555 port or you can also try with adb connect Android.local

Answer (score 1):

I did try the ADB approach but didn't seem to work for me either. It is possible to Debug android tv using USB male to male cable. If you have the cable then follow the steps.

1. Enable the Developer Options
2. Enable USB Debugging under the developer option (In the case of MI
   tv, enable the MiTv Adb option as well)
3. Connect the master end of the USB cable to your computer and the
   another end to the tv
4. Under developer options, go to Select USB Configuration. Click on the option and choose MTP(Media Transfer Protocol)

Currently, I'm using Mi tv and if you follow the above steps you can see the Tv in the android studio running devices[See the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiM0R.png).